# Including pdf in latex gives blank page, only

Tags: pdfpages, revtex

I am trying to include a pdf of the supplementary materials for my paper for submission to arXiv. It is more than one page. I know there are all kinds of questions already answered on this topic, but when I try them I either get errors I do not understand how to fix, or else I get a blank page included. The way that looks simplest to me, which does give a blank page, is given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex

When, as the first answer suggests, I include `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in the preamble and then put `\includepdf[pages={-}]{Supp.pdf}` at the end of my file, I get an extra blank page. Can anyone help? Please.

@Dr. Manuel Kuehner (I cannot respond to you in a comment, because I have no reputation): I tried a few other pdf files, they all do the same thing. Now I wonder if it has to do with the fact I'm using PCTeX (version 6.1), because as seen below, it happens with an utterly bare minimum file.

Comment 2: (I don't know why it won't let me comment on my own post . . .) I installed TexStudio with MikTeX, and it works fine, including the desired pdf file perfectly. However, when I submit it to arXiv, the file compiles fine, but it is back to having a blank page instead of the pdf file.

Here's a minimal working example (for some reason, I cannot use the article documentclass---get an error---so am sticking with what I had before):

```
\documentclass[pra,showpacs,nofootinbib,longbibliography,notitlepage]  {revtex4-1}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

. . . 

\includepdf[pages={-}]{Supp.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Unrelated to your question, but the `hyperref` package should (almost always) be loaded last; also, the `graphics` package is automatically loaded when you load `graphicx`.  You should post a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/69818), anyway, not just your preamble.

Comment: Have you tried to include another pdf file? Just to be sure that the problem is file/document independent.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.